# Reference-Type Parameters and Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am passing the list as a parameter to a method. The list values remains unchanged After Linq Where clause.

```
    void ChangeList(List<int> list)
    {
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list = list.Where(c => c > 1).ToList();
        list.Add(3); // List values: 2, 3
    }

    void Test()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(0);

        this.ChangeList(list);

        // List values: 0, 1, 2
    }
```

Probably, C# is acting like functional programing in Linq queries.

What's causing this behavior? To avoid any unexpected mistakes, I want to know exactly what caused this situation.

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: `ToList` creates a new list which is not related to your original list. Either don't use LINQ, return the list from the method or use `ref List<int> list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is not LINQ but that your List argument is passed by value, so in your outer code you still have the modified copy of the List that you passed but not the new one created by the `ToList` method inside the method `ChangeList`.

To get the new list created by the ToList method you have to pass the argument by reference in this way :

```
  void ChangeList(ref List<int> list)
```

***Remember that by default C# is pass by value .***

Answer (score 1):

`ToList` creates a new list which is not related to your original list. [Passing Reference-Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by
>   the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you
>   cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot
>   use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it
>   persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the
>   ref or out keyword.

You have three options:

Don't use LINQ

```
void ChangeList(List<int> list)
{
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(list[i] <= 1) list.RemoveAt(i);
    list.Add(3); // List values: 2, 3
}
```

or  return the list from the method

```
List<int> GetList(List<int> list)
{
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(list[i] <= 1) list.RemoveAt(i);
    list.Add(3); // List values: 2, 3
    return list;
}
// ...
list = GetList(list);
```

or use [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

```
void ChangeList(ref List<int> list)
{
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list = list.Where(c => c > 1).ToList();
    list.Add(3); // List values: 2, 3
}
// ...
this.ChangeList(ref list);
```